# Spring Boot project slow startup in Eclipse debug mode

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, spring-boot, debugging

I wrote a little Spring project based on mariadb, hibernate, spring-boot and other common libraries in Eclipse. When I run my application normally, it completes its startup in about ten seconds:

```
2019-11-07 19:53:47.539  INFO 2887 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.11.Final}
2019-11-07 19:53:47.541  INFO 2887 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-11-07 19:53:47.687  INFO 2887 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-11-07 19:53:47.799  INFO 2887 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
2019-11-07 19:53:55.078  INFO 2887 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@3400d6fa'
2019-11-07 19:53:55.083  INFO 2887 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-11-07 19:53:55.336  INFO 2887 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-11-07 19:53:55.681  INFO 2887 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-11-07 19:53:55.706  WARN 2887 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-11-07 19:53:55.893  INFO 2887 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-11-07 19:53:55.897  INFO 2887 --- [           main] petmenu.Application                      : Started Application in 10.373 seconds (JVM running for 11.18)
```

When I start it in Debug mode, it takes ten times that.

```
2019-11-07 19:36:40.265  INFO 2108 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.3.11.Final}
2019-11-07 19:36:40.267  INFO 2108 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2019-11-07 19:36:40.615  INFO 2108 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.4.Final}
2019-11-07 19:36:40.792  INFO 2108 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MariaDB103Dialect
2019-11-07 19:36:48.625  INFO 2108 --- [           main] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@57afe44b'
2019-11-07 19:36:48.628  INFO 2108 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2019-11-07 19:36:48.972  INFO 2108 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2019-11-07 19:37:44.033  INFO 2108 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2019-11-07 19:37:51.931  WARN 2108 --- [           main] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2019-11-07 19:38:19.658  INFO 2108 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2019-11-07 19:38:19.722  INFO 2108 --- [           main] petmenu.Application                      : Started Application in 103.693 seconds (JVM running for 105.206)
```

I noticed that this task in particular takes almost one minute, while it's instantaneous in normal boot.

```
2019-11-07 19:36:48.972  INFO 2108 --- [           main] o.h.h.i.QueryTranslatorFactoryInitiator  : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
```

Comment: Try to set the log level to DEBUG, you may see more info. Make sure you have enough memory for eclipse and the project - use eg. jvisualvm to see. Check if you have active breakpoints (specially on fields), try to deactivate them. In the end, you may run with profiler like Java Flight Recorder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Auto Solution: launch a clean execution of Eclipse.

If you're on your IDE standalone

```
eclipse --clean
```

If you're on Spring Tool Suite

```
STS --clean
```

You got to use it just once, it will clear its cache and subsequent calls would be useless.

Answer (score 10):

I select skip all breakpoints option under the run or press (CTRL+ALT+B) as shortkey. For my STS, debug mode start was faster than before

Step 1 :
Once we apply (CTRL+ALT+B) breakpoints are disabled, then start ur server it will run fastly.

Step 2 :
Again enable breakpoints using same shortcut,then u can able to debug.

Note : Unless applying Step2 , we can't debug application.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Comment: I indeed removed all my breakpoints from eclipse, I had a ton, which unstuck the situation, thanks

Answer (score 1):

I select skip all breakpoints option under the run or press (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) as shortkey. For my STS, debug mode start was faster than before

Step 1 : Once we apply (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) breakpoints are disabled, then start ur server it will run fastly.
Step 2 : Again enable breakpoints using same shortcut,then u can able to debug.

Note : Unless applying Step2 , we can't debug application.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is normal functionality. Eclipse uses resources and debug mode will use a LOT of resources.

Comment: It seems to me a difference too large. Until some time ago I got a delay under 10 secs. But I can't find what could be the change I made that triggers the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Spring Boot you can set this in your application.properties file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults=false
```

and

```
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
```

Comment: The second one is obviously Postgre-related. I use MariaDB and set the correct dialect together with the first property but nothing changed.

Comment: I tried set these properties but I did not observe obvious positive change on the speed of STS

Answer (score 0):

If you add a Java field watchpoints on a variable, in the debug model, it will take more time to startup. Remove the breakpoint, it starts much quicker.